# how to send multiple methods as string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, methods, hash, send

I've got model **Automation**, which has column **:data, type: :text**, serialized as **hash**.

Given record with hash as

```
{
1=>"goto 'seznam.cz'", 
2=>"text_field(placeholder: 'jméno').set 'Someone@seznam.cz'", 
3=>"text_field(placeholder: 'heslo').set 'Pass123'", 
4=>"button(xpath: //form[@class='login-form']//button[.='Přejít do Emailu']).click"
}
```

And I object **browser** throught selenium-webdriver & I want call those hashes as sequence methods, something like:

```
automation = Automation.find(params[:automation_id])
automation.data.keys.each do |key|
  browser.send(automation.data[key])
end
```

Yet it doesn't work coz I'm trying to send multiplte method names as one.
First can be solved as *browser.send(:goto, 'seznam.cz')*, yet It doesn't help me in a bigger scale, is there any way to solve it without trying to create some impossible parser(for me at least).

Those methods works as

```
browser.text_field(placeholder: 'jméno').set 'Someone@seznam.cz'
```

of course, but I want somehow to automatize it within loop from that hash.

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There's obviously a lot of code missing here since this seems to need some kind of parsing to work properly. It also looks like you're executing arbitrary code which can be extremely dangerous.

Comment: you could use `eval`, but again, don't execute code provided by strangers

Comment: Those strings are just manually added into db, so I can store that progress, so It's mine code, I just didn't found better way how to store step-by-step code. @maxple eval seems to work, so is it okay if that's mine code or is there better way to do it ? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Marek, if my answer is satisfactory, please select it.  Otherwise please explain what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that what you mean by:

```
2=>"text_field(placeholder: 'jméno').set 'Someone@seznam.cz'",
```

Is that you want to (effectively) call:

browser.text_field(placeholder: 'jméno').set('Someone@seznam.cz')

then your question isn't as simple as you may think, just calling the first item as a method.  In this case the first "item" is a string which actually contains ruby code.

That's why maxple has suggested using eval, but eval has a number of issues.

If you own all of the strings then you can use eval, but if someone else can edit those strings then they can execute arbitrary code.  I suppose you have that problem no matter what.

So one option is to simply use an eval loop with "browser.#{method}(#{param})" where (method,param) are pulled from the string.

We could clean this up a bit first by looking at a simpler example:

```
1=>"goto 'seznam.cz'",
```

If this was really all you wanted to do in each case, just specify a method and params, then you could clean it up a bit with a more interesting data structure, such as:

```
1 => { method: :goto, args: ['seznam.cz'] }
```

Then you could do:

```
browser.send(automation.data[key][:method],*automation.data[key][:args])
```

And allow multiple arguments, for example.  If you need to store this in a simple database, you can at least have different columns for the method and args, and convert the method string to a method symbol with to_sym

But this doesn't help you with the more complicated "automations" in things like step 2, because the method there is actually the result of another method call with another argument.

If you really need all of this to be stored in some sort of automation database, instead of being simple ruby code, then one option would be to break things up into *single* method calls, and save any intermittent values you need.  Maybe something like:

```
object         method         arg
------         ------         ---
browser        goto           'seznam.cz'
browser        text_field     placeholder: 'jméno'
previous       set            'Someone@seznam.cz'"
```

Where if the 'object' is 'browser', then you send the method to the browser, but if the 'object' is 'previous' then you send the method to the result of the previous call.

You'll need to figure out how to deal with the "placeholder: 'jméno'" which is effectively constructing a hash as an argument, I'll leave that exercise to the reader.

Perhaps at this point you're wondering if you really should be storing ruby code in a database.  That's a very good question.  ruby code is usually much happier in a ruby file.  :)

---

Also, as another general point, you have:

```
automation.data.keys.each ...
```

But you've numbered your keys, which presumably means you want to call them in a certain order.  To ensure this, you should probably use an ordered set such as an array instead of a hash indexed by integers, or else you can in the very least sort the keys, i.e.:

```
automation.data.keys.sort.each ...
```

Comment: (Incidentally, as far as the hash argument, you can also (probably) just send it as an array of (key,value) - another reason to allow for multiple arguments.)